# Error converting Linq parallequery to ienumerable

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

Using Linqpad to work out my query, get the above error on:

```
(from bp in basepay_records
select new { empID = bp.Prep_emp, loc = bp.Prep_loc }).Union
                (
                    from ass in emp_assignments
                    select new { empID = ass.Prea_emp, loc = ass.Prea_loc }
                )
```

I have tried it with and without the paren on the first query, no diff.  This union is part of a larger query, and this will end up sitting in a subquery that is used in a join, so I can't do the usual, though I did it test it as a stand alone query and it failed, saying no definition for Union:

```
var q1 = from bp in basepay_records select new { empID = bp.Prep_emp, loc = bp.Prep_loc };

var q2 = from ass in emp_assignments select new { empID = ass.Prea_emp, loc = ass.Prea_loc };

q1.Union (q2).Dump ("Union");
```

I confirmed that all the datatypes match.

Full error message is:

> Cannot execute text selection: 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Union(System.Linq.ParallelQuery, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery'

Comment: Do you know what the specific error message is.  One possibility would be type for empID or loc is different in each anonymous type.  For example one might be long and while other is int.

Comment: What is basepay_records ?

Comment: basepay_records and emp_assignments are tables.

Comment: Did you call `AsParallel` on one of the objects but not another?

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now.  I had to split it into 2 queries, which seems stupid, but there you go.  Let me know if you have a beter way:

```
var q1 = from mstr in emp_master_records
                            join loctab in
                                (
                                    from bp in basepay_records
                                    select new { empID = bp.Prep_emp, loc = bp.Prep_loc }
                                )
                            on mstr.Prem_emp equals loctab.empID
                            where mstr.Prem_email.StartsWith("TEST_USER")
                            select loctab.loc;

var q2 = from mstr in emp_master_records
                            join loctab in
                                (
                                    from ass in emp_assignments
                                    select new { empID = ass.Prea_emp, loc = ass.Prea_loc }
                                )
                            on mstr.Prem_emp equals loctab.empID
                            where mstr.Prem_email.StartsWith("GREGORY_RANDALL")
                            select loctab.loc;

q1.Union(q2).Dump ("Union");
```